# Ant Design Space component generate import error on ssr rendering

Tags: reactjs, next.js, antd, server-side-rendering

I'm doing a react project along with Nextjs 14.0.4 using app directory. inside the app directory I have a [adId] folder and a page.tsx file like this:

```
import AdDetailsBody from '@/parts/AdDetails/AdDetailsBody/AdDetailsBody';
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';

async function getItem(){
// fetch data from server.
}

const page = async ({ params }: { params: { adId: string[] } }) => {
  const selectedAd = await getItem(params.adId[0]);

  return <AdDetailsBody ad={selectedAd.data} />;
};

export default page;
```

then in my AdDetailsBody component I have something like this:

```
import { AdSerializer } from '@/lib/types/ad';
import AdDescription from '../AdDescription/AdDescription';

type AdDetailsBodyProps = {
  selectedAd: AdSerializer;
};

const AdDetailsBody: React.FC<AdDetailsBodyProps> = ({ selectedAd }) => {
  return (
    <div>
        <AdDescription description={selectedAd.description} />
    </div>
   
  );
};

export default AdDetailsBody;
```

and here is my adDescription component:

```
import {Space} from 'antd'

type AdDescriptionProps = {
  description: string;
};
const AdDescription: React.FC<AdDescriptionProps> = ({ description }) => {
  return (
    <Space>
      <div>Othe Informations</div>
      <div>{description}</div>
    </Space>
  );
};

export default AdDescription;
```

If I replace this Space component with for a example a normal  it works fine again

this is the error that I receive in browser console:

```
Error: Element type is invalid. Received a promise that resolves to: undefined. Lazy element type must resolve to a class or function.
```

and in my nextjs server console:

```
Internal error: Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

Comment: To me it sounds like you forgot an export statement or a return keyword somewhere.